# charset `Windows-1256′ not supported

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, dashboard

Im facing a problem with my Wordpress Dashboard , Its displaying a warring in the main page and when adding a menu page, its states:

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `Windows-1256' not supported, assuming utf-8 in /home1/khaledal/public_html/site/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 1021
```

I have tried to check the file mentioned in the warring but with no luck as I cant find this specific Charset which is `Windows-1256`

Comment: Check what is configured as `default_charset` in your php.ini.

Comment: there is no such line in the file ! 
Should I add it ?

EDIT : I added default_charset = "utf-8" the file but no luck

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, the [htmlspecialchars](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function uses `ini_get("default_charset")` when no charset is passed.

I suggest you set your [default_charset](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) to `"UTF-8"`.

If (as it seems is the case) your setting is explicitly `"Windows-1256"` you might want to watch out for other problems in case that was deliberate for some reason.

Comment: Hello , Thank you for your reply But in what file should I edit this ? in wp-config.php the default is already UTF-8

Comment: It's a PHP setting. Check the second link I gave you

Comment: Ok, I've seen the link but it states its for a file called PHP.ini 
theres no such file in Wordpress , Should I create one ? and if so where should I include it.

Comment: Hello !! I just wanted to say I fixed the problem by installing a plugin to edit the local php.ini and It worked !! Thank you for all your replies

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the problem by installing a plugin called [PHP Settings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-settings/) ! 
Just enter the line default_charset = "utf-8" and your done !!